# Matlab function input for a input that changes

Tags: matlab

How can I use a changing input when calling a function? the problem I am having is that I have to write a code in Matlab for the explicit method for parabolic partial differential equations  and the initial condition is `u(x,0) =sin(pi*x)`

when calling the function i write

`explicit( 0,0,sin(pi*x),0,0,1,0,1,3,2,0.25,0.25)`

The rest of the input functions refers to different values and boundary conditions.

where `sin(pi*x)` refers to the problem area of code to me. In the code self I write for this boundary condition

```
for j = 1:(n+2)
i = (n+2)
 x = (a -h) + h*j
 u(i,j) = Y_below
end
```

`Y_below` refers to `u(x,0) = sin(pi*x)`

This works exactly how i want it to when the boundary condition `Y_below`  is equal to any number. I do not know how to use the changing x when calling my function

I have tried Google and the closest to this I can get is varargin but I do not know how to use it.
I am new to Matlab and this is the first program I have had to write for an assignment. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by changing x? Does the value change after you call the function, or is it just a vector that can have different lengths?

Comment: The x changes its value according to the loop inside the function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but
if you define your function as follows:

```
function output = myfunction(input1, input2, varargin)
```

then `varargin` is a infunction argument that collects all
other arguments apart form input1, input2. This means that
if you call this function as below:

```
outp = myfunction(inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5);
```

then within this function the following will hold:

```
input1 = inp1;
input2 = inp2;
varargin{1} = inp3;
varargin{2} = inp4;
varargin{3} = inp5;
```

you can check (within a function) the number of
passed arguments with `nargin`.

Comment: This does help with at least understanding the varargin function, although the function does not quite work with what I had in mind. I have however just decided to enter the boundary when it is someone like sin(pi*x) into the function code itself, then it works fine thereafter.